# How to provide certain functionality in python if specific modules are installed?

Tags: python, module, lxml

The following situation: I've written a module that provides some functionality. In doing so it can invoke some commands and parse their output. At some point I now extended this module by enabling it to parse XML output. Of course from that time on this module now has a dependency to `lxml`. I did not give that much of a thought as `lxml` is not a very big deal.

Until I - just be chance - happened to use my python module on a Raspbian installation. As this installation was quite new I tried to install `lxml` using `pip`. Which failed to compile on that platform. (I guess because 500 MByte of memory is not enough to build `lxml` on such a platform.)

Now I'm wondering: Could my module be implemented in such a way that it provides a method to process XML data if and only if `lxml` is installed already? This functionality is not essential and rarely used. What would be the best pythonic approach to provide a module with basic functionality but get a bit more functionality if some other modules are available as well? My idea would be to perform some kind of test for the presence of a specific module and if that fails to raise an exception. How could that be accomplished in python in a good way? I'm using the default implementation provided on Linux. Can that functionality be achieved in a way that does not break using this python source code on other python interpreter/compiler platforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attempt the import. Set flags based on success.

```
try:
  import foo
  fooavailable = True
except ImportError:
  fooavailable = False
```

Comment: Does this work with jpython or cpython? I once I attempted to compile a python program (for some very specific reason). I guess that compiler might have complained about such code, but that's not a use case I'm aiming for. Question: If an interpreter runs across `import foo` multiple times, is that a problem?